# remove .gz file metadata without having to unzip it

Tags: compression, gzip, zip

http://www.zlib.org/rfc-gzip.html

I'd like to remove metadata from a .gz file (as well as zero MTIME and FLG), as if the file were created by `gzip -n`.

```
(if FLG.FEXTRA set)

+---+---+=================================+
| XLEN  |...XLEN bytes of "extra field"...| (more-->)
+---+---+=================================+

(if FLG.FNAME set)

+=========================================+
|...original file name, zero-terminated...| (more-->)
+=========================================+

(if FLG.FCOMMENT set)

+===================================+
|...file comment, zero-terminated...| (more-->)
+===================================+

(if FLG.FHCRC set)

+---+---+
| CRC16 |
+---+---+
```

But I don't want to gupzip it first and then gzip it. How can I read the header and discard it then write the rest in a new file?

Comment: If the header were at the end of the file ... maybe. But in general, you can not excise a section of a file without rewriting it, even an uncompressed file.

Comment: You can do a `zgrep -Pv 'exclude-regex' file | gzip > file.new`.  Inplace I have no tricks for.

Comment: @mob if removing the requirement of inplace. How the header can be read and then stripped off?

Comment: @toolic I am not asking for a recommendation. I am asking for a solution. please open the post.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13  I am not asking for a recommendation. I am asking for a solution. please open the post.

Comment: @Ed Morton  I am not asking for a recommendation. I am asking for a solution. please open the post.